# How to read a specific rows in CSV file in R language starting from first row, up-to some row without using of index

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

While reading a table from a CSV file using

```
df <- read.csv(file.choose(),TRUE,",",blank.lines.skip = TRUE,  comment.char = '#')
```

method, this will remove blank lines and comments lines (# represents comments). After that I want to read only few rows starting from first row, and stop when some  characters comes in the row (access without index or row number) which is not a data part.

Comment: Not much clear to me what your goal is. Check also the `nrows` argument of `?read.table` (or `read.csv`).

Comment: you can use which to remove columns where character is there. Still question you asked is very unclear

Comment: in CSV file, say up-to 15 rows there is the required data. in next row, there is having some text which is not required. so I want to stop reading of CSV (or I need data up to 15th row)when such case occurs but without giving  **nrow** .

Comment: is there any other way to read the CSV with that senerio?

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- read.csv("D:/df.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)[which(read.csv("D:/df.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)$Column_name == "rowValue_to_stop"),]
```

Here it will stop reading rows when the condition in which clause satisfy.